# Git fails to push with fatal: unable to access Send failure: Connection was reset

Tags: git, networking

My IDE's git and `git bash` worked as expected, until an antivirus deleted several files from the system. Now `git push` returns

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/60trees/my_project.git/': Send failure: Connection was reset
```

I've tried to reinstall git, but that didn't help. What is the right way to troubleshoot and fix the issue?

---

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRACE_CURL=1 GCM_TRACE=1 git push
15:01:48.426040 exec-cmd.c:244          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
15:01:48.434036 git.c:463               trace: built-in: git push
15:01:48.434036 run-command.c:659       trace: run_command: GIT_DIR=.git git remote-https origin https://gitlab.com/60trees/my_project.git
15:01:48.468036 exec-cmd.c:244          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
15:01:48.474036 git.c:749               trace: exec: git-remote-https origin https://gitlab.com/60trees/my_project.git
15:01:48.474036 run-command.c:659       trace: run_command: git-remote-https origin https://gitlab.com/60trees/my_project.git
15:01:48.498768 exec-cmd.c:244          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
15:01:48.513496 http.c:870              == Info: Couldn't find host gitlab.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
15:01:48.684367 http.c:870              == Info:   Trying 172.65.251.78:443...
15:01:48.826655 http.c:870              == Info: Connected to gitlab.com (172.65.251.78) port 443
15:01:48.826655 http.c:870              == Info: ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
15:01:48.837666 http.c:843              => Send SSL data, 0000000005 bytes (0x00000005)
15:01:48.837666 http.c:858              => Send SSL data: .....
15:01:48.837666 http.c:870              == Info: TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
15:01:48.837666 http.c:843              => Send SSL data, 0000000512 bytes (0x00000200)
15:01:48.837666 http.c:858              => Send SSL data: ........C........^....=..l...<.H...H.. }..Z\......9.s}.e....
15:01:48.837666 http.c:858              => Send SSL data: .h...j.[IV..>.......,.0.........+./...$.(.k.#.'.g.....9.....
15:01:48.837666 http.c:858              => Send SSL data: 3.....=.<.5./.....u.........gitlab.com......................
15:01:48.837666 http.c:858              => Send SSL data: ...................h2.http/1.1.........1.....*.(............
15:01:48.837666 http.c:858              => Send SSL data: .............................+........-.....3.&.$... .>2.j.p
15:01:48.837666 http.c:858              => Send SSL data: ..s"l..o$.=V)gwQj[......Z...................................
15:01:48.837666 http.c:858              => Send SSL data: ............................................................
15:01:48.837666 http.c:858              => Send SSL data: ............................................................
15:01:48.837666 http.c:858              => Send SSL data: ................................
15:01:48.837666 http.c:870              == Info: Send failure: Connection was reset
15:01:49.003525 http.c:870              == Info:  CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
15:01:49.003525 http.c:870              == Info:  CApath: none
15:01:49.003525 http.c:870              == Info: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to gitlab.com:443
15:01:49.003525 http.c:870              == Info: Closing connection
15:01:49.003525 http.c:870              == Info: Send failure: Connection was reset
15:01:49.003525 http.c:870              == Info: Send failure: Connection was reset
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/60trees/my_project.git/': Send failure: Connection was reset
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was following the project. It turns out that project contained a lot of files in `res` folder. Even though this folder was in `.gitignore` these files were somehow tracked by `git`.
Take home message: your data should be stored outside of the project, just to be safe.